# R novice and trying to improve the appearance of grouped box plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot

I found some online datasets and managed to make some complex box plots that had most of the features I was looking for. I'd appreciate the community's help in making these plots look better, such as:

- removing axes lines,
- adding tick marks and making them point inwards,
- changing the background color or font of `facet_wrap`,
- and removing "Label" in my attached plots.

The program Veusz allows you to change whisker mode to (e.g. I.5 IQR, 9/91 percentile, 1 stddev) and it would be nice to have that option as well. I also don't understand why the data points in my first box plot (linked below) are off center.

Linked below are screen shots of some grouped box plots that I made from my own data. I learn best by breaking and fixing things, and if someone has the time to write out the code for a box plot with lots of features, I will deconstruct it to see what each part does and search for the code online to get a better understanding of how it works.

1. [Box plot of my data 1](https://ibb.co/hf25dB9)
2. [Box plot of my data 2](https://ibb.co/TvC2NVB)
3. [Box plot of my data 3](https://ibb.co/60P65MQ)

```
    structure(list(X. = structure(c(1L, 12L, 23L, 34L, 45L, 56L, 
    67L, 71L, 72L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 
    14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
    28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
    42L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
    57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 68L, 69L, 70L
    ), .Label = c("# 1", "# 10", "# 11", "# 12", "# 13", "# 14", 
    "# 15", "# 16", "# 17", "# 18", "# 19", "# 2", "# 20", "# 21", 
    "# 22", "# 23", "# 24", "# 25", "# 26", "# 27", "# 28", "# 29", 
    "# 3", "# 30", "# 31", "# 32", "# 33", "# 34", "# 35", "# 36", 
    "# 37", "# 38", "# 39", "# 4", "# 40", "# 41", "# 42", "# 43", 
    "# 44", "# 45", "# 46", "# 47", "# 48", "# 49", "# 5", "# 50", 
    "# 51", "# 52", "# 53", "# 54", "# 55", "# 56", "# 57", "# 58", 
    "# 59", "# 6", "# 60", "# 61", "# 62", "# 63", "# 64", "# 65", 
    "# 66", "# 67", "# 68", "# 69", "# 7", "# 70", "# 71", "# 72", 
    "# 8", "# 9"), class = "factor"), Label = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Sample 1", "Sample 2", "Sample 3"
    ), class = "factor"), Rescan = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Rescan 0", "Rescan 1", "Rescan 2", "Rescan 3"
    ), class = "factor"), Porosity = c(15.19, 15.72, 15.83, 15.57, 
    15.11, 14.15, 17.24, 17.53, 18.21, 18.8, 18.32, 19.59, 17.4, 
    17.98, 19.33, 18.94, 18.32, 18.17, 19.67, 20.55, 19.04, 18.18, 
    19.59, 18.19, 18.97, 18.64, 18.83, 17.24, 18.09, 17.74, 22.28, 
    22.29, 21.35, 21.96, 23.12, 22.9, 22.9, 21.06, 23.34, 22.82, 
    21.42, 20.48, 21.22, 22.75, 21.62, 22.24, 24.28, 20.48, 14.79, 
    13.69, 13.4, 14.46, 14.13, 13.55, 20.67, 19.81, 21.2, 20.77, 
    22.29, 21.94, 19.49, 19.29, 19.43, 20.31, 21.77, 19.39, 22.37, 
    21.46, 21.86, 21.58, 21.82, 23.02)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -72L))
```

Comment: what do you mean by ticks pointing inward?

Comment: Im not sure what the wisker mode bit means. Could you link to an example of what you want?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining these terms fully. The first link shows box plots with 1 standard deviation and 1.5 IQR (interquartile range). The second link is an example of tick marks pointing inwards. The third link is to a Github page that has code for 1.5 IQR. Basically, the ends of the box plot are equal to the top and bottom quartiles multiplied by 1.5 (see line 86).  [link](https://ibb.co/jkm3g3h)
[link](https://ibb.co/SdyzgD3) [link](https://github.com/veusz/veusz/blob/master/veusz/widgets/boxplot.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of your plot with the things you wanted to do. I suppose you can adjust the code to your needs from here:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(Label,Porosity,fill=Label))+
  geom_boxplot()+

  # shift strips down
  facet_wrap(~Rescan, strip.position = "bottom")+
  # add exact points
  geom_point(alpha=0.2)+
  # add your preferred colors here (hexcode also works fine)
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue","green"))+
  # appearance
  theme_classic()+
  # legend options
  theme(legend.title      = element_blank(),
        legend.text       = element_text(color ="black", size = 8),
        legend.position   = "top", # "bottom" or "right"
        legend.key.size   = unit(1, "cm"),
        legend.spacing.x  = unit(5, "mm"),
        legend.direction  = "horizontal", # or "vertical"
        legend.background = element_blank())+
  # reverse legend keys
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = F))+ # set T to take action
  # scaling y-axis
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,max(mydata$Porosity)),breaks = seq(0,max(mydata$Porosity,10)))+
  # paramaters of the axes
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(color = "black", angle = 0, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, size = 8),
    # axis.title  = element_blank(), # activate for no axis titles
    axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.5), # use element_blank() for no lines
    axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.1, "cm"), # negative values turn them inside
    plot.background = element_blank(),
    text = element_text(family = "Arial"),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside")+ # or "inside"
  # name your axes
  ylab("your y lab")+
  xlab("your x lab")+
  # add x-axis in each facet
  annotate("segment", y=0,yend=0,x=0,xend=Inf)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for taking the time to write the code out. It's only my second day programming so all of this is very new to me.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to hit the check-mark on the left if this is your preferred answer for your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefulyy this answers some of the questions, but to be honest it's hard to pull out the individual questions you are asking. Perhaps put them in dot points?

**overall look:**

There are some pre-made themes you can try, I like:

1. `theme_void()`     - removes most things
2. `theme_classic()`  - makes the background nicer to look at
3. `theme_minimal()`  - removes the outer border and makes the background prettier

You can add them as a layer with `+ theme_void()` on the end of the plotting code.

For all other specific customisations look at `?theme()` as there are a whole bunch of things you can do.

**labels:**

To remove the title 'label' add `labs(legend = '')` as a layer. You can also use this to modify the x, y, caption and title text.

If you want to remove the legend entirely, you can add `show.legend = F` inside your `geom_jitter()` layer. (e.g. `geom_jitter(show.legend = F)`) This will mean it shows on the graph, but nothing appears in the legend.

**facets:**

To change the colour of the background in `facte_wrap` use `theme(strip.background = element_rect(color = 'desired_colour'))`

To change the colour of the text in `facte_wrap` use `theme(strip.text = element_text(color = 'desired_colour'))`

**axis lines:**

add `theme(axis.line = element_blank())`

**points:**

Your points are off center due to the `geom_jitter()`. Try `geom_point()` instead.

Comment: Hi RAB, thanks for your help with themes, jitter and facets. My points are now centered in the boxplot.